# Petapoco + Stored Procedure + ViewModel + MVC3 - pull data using multitable queries in a stored procedure and fetch in front end using VIEWMODEL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures, petapoco

I am working on a web based penny auction portal. I am using PetaPoco as my data access class library with Asp.net MVC 3 architecture. I am facing an issue with multi-table data pull using stored procedure. I have created a view model POCO for mapping stored procedure fields, that I need on the front end.

**View model:**

```
public class BiddersViewModel
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfBids { get; set; }
    public int AuctionId { get; set; }
    public int BidId { get; set; }
    public decimal BidAmount { get; set; }       
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var context = new PetaPoco.Database("DataContext");
    return View(context.Query<dynamic>("exec udsp_Bidders_SelectAll"));
}
```

### What I need

I need to pull the data from the database with multiple joins and display on the view using stored procedure (using my view model class).

Comment: Does your proc return data in the same form as your BiddersViewModel? If it does, is there a reason you don't replace 'dynamic' in your Query call with BiddersViewModel?

Comment: What @patmortech said is correct. Also be careful passing in the result of Query<> into the View directly as then it will only run the query when you iterate over the list of items in the view. The Fetch<> method is a much better option.

Comment: thanks i tried this and now it works!

Comment: var context = new PetaPoco.Database("DataContext");
            var results= context.Fetch<BiddersViewModel>(";exec udsp_Bidders_SelectAll;");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your stored procedure returns the same column names as you use in your POCO class, you can change your code to:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var context = new PetaPoco.Database("DataContext");
    return View(context.Fetch<BiddersViewModel>("exec udsp_Bidders_SelectAll"));
}
```

and your view should work as expected, because you're likely having a strong type view with defined model type as `Ienumerable<BiddersViewModel>`.

Don't worry in case your stored procedure returns more columns that you defined within your POCO view model class. Just make sure that those that you wan't mapped have correct names (or use `ColumnAttribute` to map them to properties).

Regarding `Fetch`/`Query` difference is just that if you use `Fetch` you will be reading records in your controller action, but if you use `Query` and pass that to your view, you will be reading records in the view. It's usually a better practice to **prepare the data** in controller action and **use that data** in the view. To support this pattern you should either use `Fetch` or `Query<T>().ToList()` in your controller action.

But if you need to manipulate those results for some reason in the view (if it can't be done any other way) then use `Query` and pass actual enumerator to view which will then manipulate results and read them accordingly.